# Drawing bitmap on TMetafileCanvas has no results

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am executing: FCanvas.Draw method on fcanvas of TMetafileCanvas type.

The problem is that the drawn image is:

- not visible when document printed to QPrinter local pdf printer
- is visible on BullzipPdf local printer
- is visible in xps file type

What does it depend on? Why does it behave that way?

EDIT
I forgot to mention that canvas is being printed by using StretchDraw on Printer.Canvas.

---

I have found by chance the following page:
http://www.code4sale.com/texcellent/prndib.htm

They sell some libraries which guarantee bitmaps to be printed out on every printer...
To be honest I am amazed ...

Is it really possible that printing bitmaps can be so ... complicated ...?

Comment: Hard to say. What is QPrinter? And do you have code that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Qprinter is a local pdf driver to generate pdf documents. The strange things is that on some printers the drawn bitmap is shown on others is not.

Comment: You're freeing the metafile canvas before drawing the metafile, right?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes, otherwise I would not print anything

Comment: Ok, but I thought you said it doesn't print anything..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz The whole document is printed except for the drawn image.

Comment: Try not to use a local pdf driver but a 100% Delphi component able to write PDF content directly from your `TMetaFile`, e.g. our [Open Source SynPDF unit](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=PDF%20Engine), which works fine with Delphi 7, is probably faster and uses less resources, and handles StretchDraw of any bitmap or metafile. And you won't need to install the PDF printer driver (with all its potential versioning issue and such).

Comment: well, the problem is that I am testing this functionality on local pdf printer, but initially that strange issue happend in production on konica bizhub driver ...

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, I have edited the question pasting the link to the external site with a delphi component, Have you ever thought about it?